# Change the look of Ckeditor's toolbar to look like Redactor's toolbar?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Is it possible to change the look of Ckeditor's toolbar so it can look like [Redactor's toolbar](http://imperavi.com/redactor/). I want to make this change because all skins that are available on Ckeditor acquire more space and give a 90's look. On the other hand; Redactor's flat toolbar looks amazing and it acquire less space which ultimately satisfy the demand of large group of young generation.